# How to save values from a command into .json?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I have a command that every time it is triggered, it increases its value by 1, but whenever the bot goes offline, the counter goes to 0 again:

```
class Counter(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = 0

    @commands.command()
    async def increase(self, ctx):
        self.counter += 1

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Counter(bot))
```

I want to save the number into a .json file so that he is always saved and continues where he left off but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to store your data like this:

data.json

```json
{
    "counter": 0,
}
```

you can use the `json` module.

```py
import json # standard library module


def save_json():
    global loaded_json
    json.dump('data.json', loaded_json)

class Counter(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot, counter=0):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = counter

    @commands.command()
    async def increase(self, ctx):
        self.counter += 1
        save_json()

loaded_json = {}
def setup(bot):
    global loaded_json 
    # load json in startup and set your counter
    loaded_json = json.load('data.json')
    count = loaded_json["counter"]
    bot.add_cog(Counter(bot, count))
```